# Is there a way to git stash, whilst excluding a few specific files?

Tags: git, workflow, rebase

In my current firm, we unfortunately use `git rebase` like a religion, and I often finding myself using interactive rebase tools to patch up commits where there are conflicts between topic and feature and also I try to follow an atomic commit strategy sometimes where I group changes to a specific problem domain (a specific class or group of classes, for example).

*More to the point*, I often have the use case where I want to make 2 `stash` entries at once:

1. The file `diff` that I want to append to a specific commit in my history, where related changes are already committed
2. The rest of the changes which aren't related to target commit from #1

If I stash in this order however (`git stash push path/to/related/change; git stash --include-untracked`), then when I go to retreive the stash the stash during interactive rebase commit patchup proceedings, then the stash will be index 2 in the git stash, meaning I can't just write `git stash pop`, I have to write `git stash pop stash@{1}`, and the syntax is really error prone and distracting to write, so I don't like doing it.

As far as I can see the viable way to solve this issue would be to able to `stash push` all working changes (& untracked) whilst excluding a fp pattern. Is this currently possible, and would it be practical/convenient for everyday usage?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly how you would plan to use/apply these 2 stashes?

Comment: Stash 1, during interactive rebase upon `edit` of a specific commit: `git stash pop; git commit --amend; git rebase --continue`

Comment: Stash 2 for returning to state when the rebase is finished and I am back at `HEAD`

Comment: Did you consider `git stash -p`? It allows you to interactively choose which files/hunks to stash.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks I didn't realise this existed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [exclude files from the `pathspec`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec).

```bash
git stash --include-untracked -- ':!path/to/exclude'
```

Comment: You cannot use exclude pathspec by itself — it must be an exclusion from something non-exclusion. Simple `.` (meaning the current directory) should do: `git stash --include-untracked -- . ':!path/to/exclude' `

Comment: @phd it worked when I tried. `git stash --include-untracked` includes all files per default.